# How to create a simple animation in Xamarin with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp

How to create simple animation invoking DrawCircle or DrawLine functions.

```
public void DrawCircle (SkiaSharp.SKPoint c, float radius, SkiaSharp.SKPaint paint);
```

I want to draw circles with delay. I have read all possible docs on C# xamarian animations and can't figure out a simple solution for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/graphics-and-animation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.animation?view=xamarin-forms.

Nothing on this problem in the above contents.

Can someone give me a tip from where to start to draw two object with a delay ?

```
public class SimpleCirclePage : ContentPage
{
    public SimpleCirclePage()
    {
        SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        Content = canvasView;
    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = Color.Red.ToSKColor(),
            StrokeWidth = 10
        };
        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 3, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);
        // I want to draw the second circle after some delay.
        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 3, info.Height / 3, 100, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `default radius` of `second circle` to `0` and then it won't be draw on the page. Then after some delay(I set `4000ms` here), you can set the `radius` to `100` and redraw the view, the second will appear. Is this you want?

```
public class SimpleCirclePage : ContentPage{

    float radius = 0;

    public SimpleCirclePage()
    {
        SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        this.Content = canvasView;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000), () =>
        {
            radius= 100;
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();

            return false;
        });
    }

     void  OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = Color.Red.ToSKColor(),
            StrokeWidth = 10
        };

        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 3, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);

        // I want to draw the second circle after some delay.
        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 3, info.Height / 3, radius, paint);
    }
}
```

You can read the document: [skiasharp/basics/animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/animation)

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT Thank you a lot! I want to put this in a foreach loop but this will help me to achieve my goal i will also see the document